# how to wait for some event to complete in jmeter load tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jmeter, load-testing

How can I waitforapagetoload in jmeter. I have entered some data and after this it usually takes some random time to execute e.g stored procedures etc. I don't know how can I do this in jemeter load tests. I tried putting constant time but still it keeps failing. Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

This is described in this tutorial if you mean you have an intermediate loading screen:

- http://www.sourcepole.ch/2011/1/4/waiting-for-a-page-change-in-jmeter

Otherwise you have nothing to do, JMeter will wait for response.